# choosing the value of BypassPrepare property

Tags: ssis

I know that setting "BypassPrepare" property to true means that preparing (parsing) query is done by the database engine I'm connecting to. Otherwise the preparation is done by integration services package but how does it matter whether parsing is done on SSIS side  or Database engine side. 
I just want to make the best choice.

Thanks ,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you set this option to true then the preparing (i.e. parsing) is done by the database engine you are connecting to.

If you set this option to false then the preparation is done by integration services package.

This option is available only for OLEDB type connections and was introduced because pacakge (sql task) cannot prepare/parse all the SQL commands that OLEDB database supports. Meaning that you would get error in parse phase and would not be able to execute the statement that is valid statement on OLEDB database but cannot be prepared/parsed by SQL task.

Comment: Why would you ever set it to False, if SSIS's parser is incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

When "BypassPrepare" is set to TRUE, parsing is done by the DB engine and hence it impacts performance.
So, we should set it to TRUE wisely or when necessary.